# Squeeze transformation in higher dimension vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

From what I have read, including on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_mapping) and a post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3000906/difference-between-scaling-and-squeezing) on MSE, **squeeze transformations** are typically defined only for *two*-dimensional vector spaces such as a Euclidean plane, where one basis vector is stretched by a scalar and the other is shrunk by the same scalar (i.e. “stretched” by the its reciprocal). A square in the Euclidean plane is transformed into a rectangle with the same area. In the canonical basis, it’s transformation matrix with determinant $1$, is
$$\begin{pmatrix}x’ \\ y’ \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 &1/a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$$
*Any reason a squeeze transformation can’t be generalized to higher dimensions?* For example, I believe in three-dimensional Euclidean space the following matrix of determinant $1$ transforms a cube into a rectangular cuboid of the same volume.

$$\begin{pmatrix}x’ \\ y’ \\ z’\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 & 0\\ 0&b&0\\0&0&1/(ab)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Obviously. And now ?

Comment: Nothing next. Was just curious if there was a reason why none of the textbooks that I read make this generalization to higher dimensions and in fact some explicitly state that squeeze transformations are ONLY defined in two dimensions. Thought I might be missing something.

Comment: Your 2d example is area preserving and your 3d example is a [volume preserving](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1895067/949989). Both are characterized by the determinant being one and there is an obvious generalization to $n$ dimensions. If we call it "squeeze" transformation or not doesn't matter. Let the nomenclature committee have their will and call only 2d a squeeze transformation.

Comment: Isn’t det=1 more general than what is typically referred to as a “squeeze” transformation which is represented in a basis as a diagonal matrix indicating that the bases scale independent of each other? For example the matrix for a shear transformation along one basis vector may have det=1 and preserve area/volume but not scale the bases independently consistent with the notion of a “squeezing” space. This is the case even in 2 dimensions.

Comment: @user175324 Historically squeeze maps were used to define maps that preserved hyperbolic angles, which are defined using the area swept out between the points on a hyperbola. If we generalize that to volumes or hypervolumes they will not necessarily squeeze out in all directions uniformly.

Comment: Thanks @CyclotomicField. Now makes sense why the focus is on 2D. I had read the relation to hyperbolic angles. Would think one could still generalize to higher dimension and assure that on squeezes out uniformly in all directions other that the one squeezing in by having the all but one diagonal element be the same, i.e., a,a,...,a,1/a^(n-1), Determinant still 1. Scales along n-1 basis vector by the same scalar a.

Comment: @user175324 you can define a map of that kind if you'd like but it's unclear what use it would have. Typically a definition gains prominence because of results related to it. If you can find something interesting to say about such matrices the definition could become popular.

Comment: Thanks @CyclotomicField. All makes sense now.